# Reading and writing files from html in Google App Engine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I am working with GAE and Python, I know python, but I don't know HTML, which seems to be what I need right now. I want to take in a text file write something in it then return it for download. I am using other people's examples, but far all I have is:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):

    #http://bukhantsov.org/2011/12/python-google-app-engine-calculator/
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""<html>
            <body>
            <form action='/' method='get' autocomplete='off'> 
            <input type='file' name='file'/><br/> 
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>""")
```

I imagine there is something I need to put in the file line so I can access what the user feeds it, but I don't know what or how to access it from the python code. So what should I do here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498771/upload-a-file-in-google-app-engine-and-making-it-downloadable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to grab the text data being sent by the user via the GET call that is defined by the form action HTML line.

Concisely, you are looking for this call:

```
file = self.request.get('file')
```

This may also be useful:

```
filename = self.request.GET['file'].filename
```

These can be used in the same location and in conjunction with your "self.response.out".

More information can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_get

Alternatively, the BlobStore APIs may be easier.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview

Possibly related:
[Upload files in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81451/upload-files-in-google-app-engine),
[Get original filename google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004476/get-original-filename-google-app-engine)

Hope that helps!
Jess

Comment: I just want to make sure of one thing, most examples show the request.get in the post function, but you said 'in the same location and in conjunction' so does it matter where I call request.get? Will if affect the results?

Comment: In general, you can use the self.request.get in either the "def get" or the "def post". The only difference is which call is being invoked. Here's a nice list of why people choose [GET vs POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

The question was answered in more detail here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700191/printing-files-in-google-app-engine