# printing files in Google App Engine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I am trying to read and print a file in Google App Engine, but the code bellow seems unresponsive. I can upload the file, and my expectation was that it would just print the text, but it does nothing. I thought about adding a submit button, but I have no idea how to link submit with pythons printing. How can I get this to print on command?

I have seen the example provided by GAE [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms), but I would first like to keep it all on one page, and second I still don't understand how the submit calls that second page.

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    #http://bukhantsov.org/2011/12/python-google-app-engine-calculator/
    def get(self):
        # build a list of operations
        self.response.out.write("""<html>
            <body>
            <form action='/' method='get' autocomplete='off'> 
            <input type='file' name='file'/><br/>
            #<input type='submit' name="test" value="submit">
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>""")
        file = self.request.get('file')
        self.response.out.write(file)
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)

def main():
    util.run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is sent using the HTTP GET method, but for file uploads you need POST. Change it from:

```
method='get'
```

to:

```
method='post'
```

You will also need to handle POST requests in a different method. The POST body itself should be available as `self.request.POST`. So you end up with something like:

```
def post(self):
    file = self.request.POST['file']
    self.response.out.write(file)
```

Comment: just that change gave me "405 Method Not Allowed The method POST is not allowed for this resource." So I put the file = and self.responce... in  def post, that almost works, but it prints out the name of the file and not the file itself, is that a python problem or html problem?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot those bits. Updated answer.

Comment: If you don't mind me bothering you one more time, do you know if there is a way to print the file on the same page as the get? All the examples I can find wipe the page then write the text.

Comment: The typical approach would be to store the file somewhere, then redirect to a page with a regular GET request that displays it. For simple cases, you could just reuse the same HTML snippet in the `post()` method and stick the file in there somewhere.